# openresty nginx, there is no work process after starting nginx

Tags: nginx, openresty

```
I work on windows 10 use built-in bash for ubantu

I installed openresty, and start it's nginx with command "nginx -p openresty-test".
```

My nginx.conf content is:

```
worker_processes  2;       
error_log logs/error.log;  
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 6699;
        location / {
            default_type text/html;

            content_by_lua_block {
                ngx.say("HelloWorld")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

problem:
    I try curl "http://localhost:6699 -i", It's blocked without any message and didn't return.
    I use web browser to visit localhost:6699, It's blocked too.

```
I run "ps -ef | grep nginx" show:
27     1  0  2433 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process ng
29     2  0  2433 ?        00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx

As we see there is only a master process, no any work process, I doubt that cause my problem,
```

how should I do?

Comment: Are you sure nginx uses your config? Where is your config reside? What is the prefix of compiled nginx (nginx -V)?

Comment: Did you take a look to logs?